# What is the proper way to get a view of any item in ListView in Dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, view, ratingbar

In my application, I create a `Dialog`. Which contain a ListView. And in my ListView I am setting a rating bar. But I am not able to get view of RatingBar. I am using two `xml` for create a complete `Dialog`.

```
 popup_dialog = new Dialog(Home_Screen.this);
        popup_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rating_layout);
        popup_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        popup_dialog.setCancelable(true);
        LayoutInflater inflater = Home_Screen.this.getLayoutInflater();

        final View rating_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_list, null);
    //  LayoutInflater rating = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //  final View rating_view = rating.inflate(R.layout.rating_list, null);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setText("Give Rating");
        lv = (ListView) popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ImageView close = (ImageView)popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        Button give_rating = (Button)popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.give_rating);
        Custum_Adapter adapter = new Custum_Adapter(Home_Screen.this, applist);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        ratingbar = (RatingBar)rating_view.findViewById(R.id.vendor_rating);

//setOnRatingBarChangeListener not responding .....may be because I am not able to get proper view.
        ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rating-->"+rating+"Position-->"+lv.getPositionForView(ratingBar), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Rating------>"+rating+"position----->"+lv.getPositionForView(ratingBar));
            }
        });
```

This is rating_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#6eb5c4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/vendor_rating"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.48"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="2.0"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:stepSize="0.1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/editbackground"
        android:hint="Tip"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is rating_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<include
    android:id="@+id/custom_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/action_bar_popup" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="290dp"
    android:background="@drawable/new_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.38"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>
     <Button 
       android:id="@+id/give_rating"  
     android:layout_width="130dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Give Rating"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/editbackground"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I am seting up rating_list.xml in dialog through CustomAdapter

```
private class Custum_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

     public Custum_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> applist) {
            this.list = applist;
        }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.rating_list, parent, false);
        }
        System.out.println("list size*******"+list.size());


        HashMap<String, String> a = list.get(position);
        System.out.println("Position of hash map----->"+position);
    //  String id = a.get("id");
        String name = a.get("provider_name");
        System.out.println("name--------->"+name);
    //  String c_cost = a.get("cost");
    //  String c_id = a.get("cost_id");
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //  TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //  TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.costing_id);
    //  TextView tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cost);
        tv.setText(name);
    //  tv1.setText(id);
    //  tv2.setText(c_id);
    //  tv3.setText(c_cost);

        return convertView;
    }
 }
```

So `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` not responding (Not printing rating on console or in Toast) may be because I am not able to get proper view of `RatingBar`. So can someone tell me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the view this way as you are setting the rating_view to any view or layout in the dialog. Create a relativeLayout or view in the dialog and add the rating_view to it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to achieve could be done more simply using a DialogFragment, from where you'll be able to access all the containing views of the dialog.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

if you still want to use a dialog, though, i believe your problem would be solved if you moved the inflate before the setContentView, so you would have a reference to the view inside the dialog. can't confirm 100% it will work, though.

```
popup_dialog = new Dialog(Home_Screen.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = Home_Screen.this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View rating_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_list, null);
        popup_dialog.setContentView(rating_view);
        popup_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        popup_dialog.setCancelable(true);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)rating_view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setText("Give Rating");
        lv = (ListView) rating_view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ImageView close = (ImageView)rating_view.findViewById(R.id.close);
        Button give_rating = (Button)rating_view.findViewById(R.id.give_rating);
        Custum_Adapter adapter = new Custum_Adapter(Home_Screen.this, applist);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        ratingbar = (RatingBar)rating_view.findViewById(R.id.vendor_rating);
        ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rating-->"+rating+"Position-->"+lv.getPositionForView(ratingBar), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Rating------>"+rating+"position----->"+lv.getPositionForView(ratingBar));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem is I need to put `ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener` in the `getView();` method of `CustomAdapter`. By this way I can get the view of `RatingBar` which is set by `CustomAdapter`  in `Dialog`.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.rating_list, parent, false);
        }
        System.out.println("list size*******"+list.size());


        HashMap<String, String> a = list.get(position);
        System.out.println("Position of hash map----->"+position);
        String name = a.get("provider_name");
        System.out.println("name--------->"+name);
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(name);   
        ratingbar = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.vendor_rating);
        ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rating-->"+rating+"Position-->"+lv.getPositionForView(ratingBar), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Rating------>"+rating+"position----->"+lv.getPositionForView(ratingBar));
            }
        });

        return convertView;
```